# SQL condition depending on result in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mySQL statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) from online_users WHERE name='lol') as online, id, name, city
FROM players 
WHERE name='lol'
AND last_action < date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
```

however I want the `last_action` interval to vary; 1 minute if `online` is 1, and 1 hour if `online` is 0

Can this be done all in one query? How so?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) from online_users WHERE name='lol') as online, id, name, city
FROM players 
WHERE name='lol'
AND last_action < date_sub(now(), interval 1 CASE WHEN online=0 THEN hour ELSE MINUTE END)
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR condition, like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) from online_users WHERE name='lol') as online, id, name, city
FROM players 
WHERE name='lol'
AND ((last_action < date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour) AND online = 1) OR (last_action < date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) AND online = 0))
```